# ICloud + Storage Error

Tags: ios, sdk, icloud, icloud-api

I am sharing my docs on iCloud using my app and it is shared well because when i delete my app and reinstall, my previous data load again, but when I go to setting -> icloud -> backup & storage, I am not able to see my app in it as well as I am not able to clear my data from icloud.

Can you please provide a solution for it?

Thanks
Kamal

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use diferrent provisioning file to this project, it will generate different folders in iCloud.

Ex: 2 provisioning files create two folded 1, 2.
When you go to setting to check files, but can not see anything because setting gets data from folder 1(empty)! But your application uses second provisioning to build.

So, go to https://developer.icloud.com/
to check your real folder that show data! And in your code, delete unnecessary icloud folder is create by unnecessary provisioning via NSFileManager

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is not my issue. I have used single profile.